# Need help getting sprites to come in from right hand side of the screen using phaser.js

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm learning the phaser framework for games right now: http://phaser.io

This is example demonstrates multiple sprites coming in from the left hand side of the screen. I'm just trying to figure out how to get them to come in from the right. There's something I'm missing.

The working example can be seen here: http://examples.phaser.io/_site/view_full.html?d=sprites&f=add+several+sprites.js&t=add%20several%20sprites

code:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, 'phaser-example', { preload:preload, create: create, update: update });

var timer = 0;
var total = 0;

function preload() {

//  37x45 is the size of each frame
//  There are 18 frames in the PNG - you can leave this value blank if the frames     fill up the entire PNG, but in this case there are some
//  blank frames at the end, so we tell the loader how many to load
game.load.spritesheet('mummy', 'assets/sprites/metalslug_mummy37x45.png', 37, 45, 18);

}

function create() {

releaseMummy();

}

function releaseMummy() {

var mummy = game.add.sprite(-(Math.random() * 800), game.world.randomY, 'mummy');

mummy.scale.setTo(2, 2);

//  If you prefer to work in degrees rather than radians then you can use Phaser.Sprite.angle
//  otherwise use Phaser.Sprite.rotation
mummy.angle = game.rnd.angle();

mummy.animations.add('walk');
mummy.animations.play('walk', 20, true);

game.add.tween(mummy).to({ x: game.width + (1600 + mummy.x) }, 20000, Phaser.Easing.Linear.None, true);

total++;
timer = game.time.now + 100;

}

function update() {

if (total < 200 && game.time.now > timer)
{
    releaseMummy();
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could set sprite position far to the right after the game bounds.

```
var mummy = game.add.sprite(800 + (Math.random() * 800), game.world.randomY, 'mummy');
```

and tween far to the left after the game bounds.

```
game.add.tween(mummy).to({ x: -(1600 + mummy.x) }, 20000, Phaser.Easing.Linear.None, true);
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lx5rZ/)